# Triangular direct connect ethernet network using the 2 possible paths (bonding + failover)

Tags: ethernet, bridge, failover

imagine this topology:

```
   A
 /   \
B --- C
```

In this situation, A can talk to B using the A <> B link of couse,
but could also use the A <> C <> B links.

Is it possible with a linux distribution to configure the network to :

1. Allow all hosts to take advantage of both path possible to an other
   host to double the bandwidth, a bit like bonding the 2 interfaces on each host
2. Allow all hosts to talk to an other host if the direct link between them has been cut, a bit like bridging the 2 interfaces on each host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Quagga is probably what you are looking for.
http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/
But beware that a configuration is not a Next-Next-Next-Finish.